# Display different contents in the menu according to the role of the user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a menu or sections only to be visible to some users. I have the role user, role admin1, and role admin2 in my database.

For example, how can I make Category 2 visible to the user and admin2 only?

```
        {
          "name": "Jack",
          "fname": "Daniel",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_USER",
          ]
        }

        {
          "name": "Rico",
          "fname": "Phil",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_ADMIN1",
          ]
        }

        {
          "name": "Admini",
          "fname": "Strator",
          "roles": [
            "ROLE_USER",
            "ROLE_ADMIN2"
          ]
        }
```

My code :

```
<ion-item class="item-stable animsvdj" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-android-contacts' : 'ion-android-contacts'"></i>
      &nbsp; Category
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.disponibilites" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-calendar-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 1</ion-item>

    <!-- Part that should be visible only by admin -->
    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.organiseVisite" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-time-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 2</ion-item>
    <!-- Part that should be visible only by admin -->

    <ion-item class="item-accordion menu-border" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.trouverUnJeune" menu-close=""><i class="ion-ios-eye-outline menu-icon"></i>   Category 3</ion-item>
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ng-if` or `ng-show` in `ion-item`

For example:

```
ng-if="item.roles === 'ROLE_ADMIN2'"
```